# Minimal length of a string that contains two strings

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, strings

We have two strings $a,b$. I want to find string $c$ that includes $a$ as a subsequence and includes $b$ as a subsequence and the length of $c$ is minimal.  Is there an efficient algorithm for this problem?

For example, if $a=1011$ and $b=0100$, the minimal string that include both: $c=101100$.  As you can see string $c$ includes both $a$ and $b$ (with the characters of $a$ appearing in the same order in $c$, possibly with other characters interspersed, and the same for $b$).

I think it can be solved by a dynamic programming algorithm.

Comment: This problem has been studied under the name [shortest common supersequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence).

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  You think it can be solved by dynamic programming; well, what dynamic programming algorithms did you come up with?  Did you come up with a recursive relation?  We want to help you understand concepts, not solve exercise problems for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the explanation [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence),

- obtain the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) of $a$ and $b$ with a (quite elementary) [dynamic programming approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#LCS_function_defined) and
- insert the characters which are *not* part of the LCS in-order and in appropriate positions.

Note that the result of neither step is necessarily unique.

Writing actual (pseudo)code, correctness proof and runtime analysis are easy exercises.

Comment: shouldn't that be shortest common supersequence? (like you suggest in your comment at the question)

Comment: Thank you, but: 1. Can you explain me this - "insert the characters which are not part of the LCS in-order and in appropriate positions." please? 2. There is clearer explanation for the LCS, because what wrote at Wikipedia is unclear...

Comment: @HendrikJan Yes. The OP looks for SCS, the algorithm gets there via an LCS.

Comment: @Yoar No, I won't. To be blunt, I think that the descriptions on Wikipedia are clear enough assuming you want to invest any time and thought yourself. I have no interest in helping you if all you want is code.

Comment: @Raphael, It's not for a code it's for an exercise that I must write in my words... I'll try to work harder but I don't understand the *meaning* of: "insert the characters which are not part of the LCS in-order and in appropriate positions". What does it mean? Can you explain me please? Thank you!

Comment: BTW @Raphael - Here you that you get just the length of it - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Relation_to_other_problems - Where you see about the second issue??

Comment: @Yoar It's explained with an example in the SCS article on Wikipedia. Say you have $a_1 \dots a_n$ as one sequence and $a_{i_1} \dots a_{i_k}$ with $k \leq n$ the LCS, you'll have to add $a_1 \dots a_{i_1-1}$, $a_{i_1+1}\dots a_{i_2 - 1}$, and so on in order to get an SCS. Similarly for $b$. Since $a_{i_x} = b_{j_x}$ for all $x \in [1..k]$ you can shuffle the parts between the characters of the LCS -- which are unequal, otherwise it would not be an LCS -- however you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: assume $a$ starts with a 1st letter $x$, hence is some $xa'$. Similarly, assume $b$ is some $yb'$.

Now what is the shortest word that contains $a$ and $b$ when $x=y$ (when $a$ and $b$ start with the same char)? And what if $x\not=y$? Finally, what if $a$ is the empty word $\epsilon$? Or if $b$ is $\epsilon$?

Solving all these cases will lead you to a dynamic programming solution.

PS: what you call "a string $s$ that includes all characters of $a$" is formally called a supersequence. Write it $a\leq s$. In particular, the *number of occurrences* of the symbols in $a$ and *their left-to-right order* must be accounted for in $s$ but not necessarily at contiguous positions.

Comment: I still don't understand - I made few examples with the hind that you gave my but I still stuck...   What with the 2nd letter (of $a$ and $b$)? What I do with it? Thank you!

Comment: And if I have $xx$, $yy$ at some place at a and b, what I need to do?

Comment: When you look at $a=xa'$ and $b=yb'$ with $x\not=y$ you may either go for $xs$ where $s$ is a supersequence of $a'$ and $b$ or for $yt$ where $t$ is a supersequence of $a$ of $b'$. Compute $s$ and $t$ and see which is shorter.

Comment: If you can explain little bit more it will be great!! Thank you!!

Comment: Run my explanations on an example. Take $a=$ TROLL and $b=$ LOL. What do you get?